# Running SharePoint 2010 on SQL Server 2014 with Compatibility Level 110?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server, infrastructure, sql-server-2012, hosting-environment

Can anyone confirm if it is supported to run SharePoint 2010 on SQL Server 2014 with Compatibility Level 110?

Have seen SQL Server 2014 and SharePoint 2010 is not a supported combination, but not sure what happens when running SQL with compatibility Level set to 110 (SQL Server 2012)?

Answer (score 0):

Contacted MS Services regarding this issue and thay said it could be done but was not supported from MS